# How do i convert excel time format to hours and minutes?

Tags: excel

I am logging some events, but on occasion i get the timestamp in a weird 0,x format.

Shown on the picture.

[image: excel time format]

I allready tried creating a column next to this and put in =Hour(F2)  example..
But the result is then 00:00

Most of the values are correct.
But some are missing out, any ideas?

Comment: DateTimes in Excel are Doubles. The integer part is the day, and the decimal part is the time. This looks (possibly) as if the strange times have been written as a string by a European (possibly French) system, where the decimal point is a ',' and not a '.'. Hence your system can't parse the string into a number. You can use the REPLACE() function: =VALUE(REPLACE(F2,2,1,".")) to change the decimal separator. Then you should be able to format as a time. But you should try and check independently that you are getting the right conversion. F2 then comes out as 16:31:34.

Comment: ahh thank you, it works with the replace..  
Cheers..  Drop a answer.

Comment: No worries ... I worked for a French firm for a while and this happened all the time!